# Images got changed in recyclerview adapter click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have used RecyclerView to display data which contains an Image and a TextView as rawitem.

My Adapter class is as below :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.RecyclerViewHolders> {

private List<MyModel> itemList;
private Context context;

private DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<MyModel> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singleview_grid_location, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.rl_main.setTag(position);
    final MyModel mainModel = itemList.get((int) holder.rl_main.getTag());
    if (mainModel.is_selected()) {
        holder.rl_main.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_theme);
        holder.iv_selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.rl_main.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.iv_selection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.txt_location_name.setText(mainModel.getLocationName());
    if (mainModel.getImagePath() != null && !mainModel.getImagePath().equals("")) {
        Constant.getImageLoader().displayImage(mainModel.getImagePath(),
                holder.iv_location_photo, Constant.getInstanceImageOptions(R.mipmap.popup_placeholder), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view2) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view2, FailReason failReason) {
                        holder.iv_location_photo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.popup_placeholder);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view2, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    }
                });
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mainModel.is_selected()) {
                mainModel.setIs_selected(false);
            } else {
                mainModel.setIs_selected(true);
            }
            itemList.set(position, mainModel);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.itemList.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txt_location_name;
    public ImageView iv_location_photo;
    public CardView card_view;
    public ImageView iv_selection;
    public RelativeLayout rl_main;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt_location_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_location_name);
        iv_location_photo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_location_photo);
        card_view = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        iv_selection = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_selection);
        rl_main = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
    }
}
}
```

The issue is that, When I am clicking on view of Recyclerview, The images got changed. Ya, The textview and my selection remains same and works accurate. The issue is image got changed for views.

What might be the issue ? Please, checkout. Thanks.

Comment: onLoadingComplete you are not changing image?

Comment: you are not setting image anywhere except for error case.

Comment: @nomag Using Universal Image Loader and Images set successfully. the issue is in image change when i click on raw item.

Comment: @nomag Selection set good, location name remains same for particular raw But, Images got changing for particular views of RecyclerView when i clicking on particular view for selection.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of doing this ??

```
holder.rl_main.setTag(position);
final MyModel mainModel = itemList.get((int) holder.rl_main.getTag());
```

You need to get the List position from the position parameter itself that onBindView provides you.
Next You should write onClickListener on Class itself and not implement inside the onBindView.Bad Practice and can create some problems.
Override Method. " getItemViewType(int position) ".
After Modifying the model.
You should do  notify item added/removed/changed/inserted based on the need and the provide position which you can get from getAdapterPosition.

Comment: @kartik You don't know about getTag() n setTag() ?

Comment: i know,, but there isn't a point using that. We used to use those in listviews.

Comment: @MashukKhan try.. this before setting recycler to adapter.
recycler_view.setItemViewCacheSize(//// array size );

Comment: What the solution is ?